# Laravel plus Ajax to implement search bar

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, searchbar

Here is my view ajax part

```
function getSearch(){
            var sr_s_id= $('#sr_s_id').val();
            var sr_name= $('#sr_name').val();
            var sr_department= $('#sr_department').val();
            var sr_semester= $('#sr_semester').val();
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type    :"POST",
                url     :"{{url('/management/sutdent')}}",
                dataType:"json",
                data    :{ s_id:sr_s_id,name:sr_name,department:sr_department,semester:sr_semester },
                success :function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });

        }
```

Here is my controller

```
public function getSearch(Request $request){
        $s_id =$request->s_id;
        $name =$request->name;
        $department = $request->department;
        $semester =$request->semester;
        $student_list=$this->UserRepository->getSearchdata($s_id,$name,$department,$semester);  
        //echo $student_list;

        return response()->json($student_list);

    }
```

here is repository

```
public function getSearchdata($s_id=null,$name=null,$department=null,$semester=null){


        return $this->user
            ->select('s_id','name','email','user_info.updated_at as editDate','semester','USN','phone','address','Department')
            ->leftjoin('user_info','s_id','user_info.school_id')
            ->where(['r_id','=','1'],['s_id','like',$s_id],['name','like',$name],['department','like',$department],['semester','like',$semester])
            ->orderBy('s_id','asc')->get();
    }
```

I have two question about my code.
First, when i clicked search bar button, it will show

> message: "Array to string conversion", exception: "ErrorException",…}

I think that is the query problem, but i have no idea how happened.

Second, does anyone have good idea to identify the request value is null or not in the repository.php? Then, I need to push the result to the where with the laravel format.

In normally php file, we will use String combining. Like

```
$Where ="something=".$a

if($something!=null)
{
    $Where.=",something=".$something;
}
```

but i have no idea how to do in the laravel language.
Have anyone can help me to solve these two problem?

---

New question : Json output.
Is it normal to show the first query one more time?
I mean ....

```
{s_id: "ym1234", name: "one", email: "test@test.com", editDate: "2018-04-12 05:54:32",…},…]
0
:
{s_id: "ym1234", name: "one", email: "test@test.com", editDate: "2018-04-12 05:54:32",…}
Department
:
"test"
USN
:
"student"
address
:
"CS123"
editDate
:
"2018-04-12 05:54:32"
email
:
"test@test.com"
name
:
"one"
phone
:
null
s_id
:
"ym1234"
semester
:
"105"
1
:
{s_id: "ym321", name: "two", email: "test@test.com", editDate: "2018-04-07 23:53:29",…}
Department
:
"test"
USN
:
"student"
address
:
"CS123"
editDate
:
"2018-04-07 23:53:29"
email
:
"test@test.com"
name
:
"two"
phone
:
null
s_id
:
"ym321"
semester
:
"106"}]
```

Comment: what is the line that error shows ?

Comment: message: "Array to string conversion", exception: "ErrorException",…}
exception
:
"ErrorException"
file
:
"D:\XAMPP\htdocs\YangMing567\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php"
line
:
198
message
:
"Array to string conversion"

Comment: there only show these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to combine all condition in one array for where condition like `where([['r_id','=','1'],['s_id','like',$s_id],['name','like',$name],['department','like',$department],['semester','like',$semester]])`

And second is you have error in your client side code and may generate same error - because you are going to alert the object that is in json format. You specified `dataType : json` means the response is converted in JSON format. If you alert your JSON object then the error is obvious.

Now, second question is -

This is what I am using in my code snippet - supposed you should have following code inside `getSearchdata` function

```
$query = $this->user
         ->select('s_id','name','email','user_info.updated_at as editDate','semester','USN','phone','address','Department')
        ->leftjoin('user_info','s_id','user_info.school_id')
        ->where('r_id','=','1');

if($s_id)
{
   $query->where('s_id','=',$s_id);
}
if($name)
{
   $query->where('name','like','%'.$name.'%');
}
if($department)
{
   $query->where('department','like','%'.$department.'%');
}
if($semester)
{
   $query->where('semester','like','%'.$semester.'%');
}
return $query->orderBy('s_id','asc')->get();
```

Let me know, whether it works for you or not...

Comment: you have figureout all possible problems

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not home two days ago. 
Yes!! Both problems was solved. Thanks for your help!! It's work, and thanks for your idea.

Comment: @Zong thanks for accepting answer and welcome. You upvote my answer to...

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi HI~ i have one more question! about my josn output

Comment: please ... feel free

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add `[ ]` in your where condition
Change your function to

```
public function getSearchdata($s_id=null,$name=null,$department=null,$semester=null){


    return $this->user
        ->select('s_id','name','email','user_info.updated_at as editDate','semester','USN','phone','address','Department')
        ->leftjoin('user_info','s_id','user_info.school_id')
        ->where([['r_id','=','1'],['s_id','like',$s_id],['name','like',$name],['department','like',$department],['semester','like',$semester]])
        ->orderBy('s_id','asc')->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `getSearchdata` function is incorrect:

```
    public function getSearchdata($s_id = null, $name = null, $department = null, $semester = null)
    {

        return $this->user
            ->select('s_id', 'name', 'email', 'user_info.updated_at as editDate', 'semester', 'USN', 'phone', 'address', 'Department')
            ->leftJoin('user_info', 's_id', 'user_info.school_id')
            ->where('r_id', '=', '1')
            ->where('s_id', 'like', $s_id)
            ->where('name', 'like', $name)
            ->where('department', 'like', $department)
            ->where('semester', 'like', $semester)
            ->orderBy('s_id', 'asc')->get();

   }
```